# Where can I find a nationwide breakdown - by race - of police detentions that did not result in an arrest or citation?

Tags: data-request

UCR statistics tell me how many people, in the year 2013, were arrested. It breaks down the data based on race and crime.

What I'm looking for is more along the lines of how many people were detained but not arrested or issued a citation. I thought there was data somewhere on the FBI Website, but I could not find it.